# How to append list data to a 'xlsx' template?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx

I want to list data append in the template `xlsx` file header that already exists in the template `xlsx` file, can we add logic if `Descrption` e.g. (`Descrption 1`, `Descrption 2`, `Descrption 3` .... `Descrption n`) came more than 4 than can we create another header `Description next number`? For next iteration create a column according to the `Description`.

**Template Input Example:-**
[image]

**Expected Output XLSX File:-**
[image]

**If I run the below script then get the output:-**
[image]

I try below this code:

```
import pandas as pd

xlsx_file = "input.xlsx"

existing_data = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file)

newData = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Brand A'],
    ['Product Title'],
    ['Description 1', 'Description 2', 'Description 3', 'Descriprion 4'],
    ['Quantity 4']
])

combined_data = pd.concat([existing_data, newData], ignore_index=False)



with pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as write:
    combined_data.to_excel(write, startcol=0, startrow=0)
```

Comment: Please clearify, i dont really understand what u want :)

Comment: @Christoph - Thanks for reply, I want to insert the `DataFrame` list data append the  `xlxs` template file `Template Input Example` as template and `Expected Output XLSX File` as expectd xlsx file.

Comment: An whats the issue, what does Not Work ?

Comment: I try but my code is not working.

Comment: What is the Output you must give more Context. Did u get Errors? How does the xlxs looks after U ran your Script ?

Comment: i dont understand what this question seeks.  how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Christoph I updated the question and add the current output, please check.

Comment: @D.L, could you please check my input template `xlsx` and expected `xlsx` file, I want to append list data into template `xlsx` file.

Comment: The main problem is how you define `newData` - it doesn't correlate with your template, so you get an incorrect concatenation. Provide proper headings when filling in new data.

Comment: As @Vitalizzare indicates; Your Dataframe 'newData' will have 4 Columns with Headers '0', '1', '2', '3' which do not relate to the existing 'template'. Hence concat to the Dataframe 'existing_data' will just add as new columns after the last column 'Quantity'.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using Pandas for this at all. Doing this directly in Openpyxl would let you make changes in the headers directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to get the data as you have shown in the **Expected Output XLSX File:-** screenshot you'd need to change your code to the following at a basic level;

Note:- the 'newData' Dataframe is modified so it has headers included that match with the template, thus the concat can incorporate the data into the existing columns.

```
import pandas as pd

xlsx_file = "input.xlsx"


existing_data = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file)

# newData = pd.DataFrame([
#     ['Brand A'],
#     ['Product Title'],
#     ['Description 1', 'Description 2', 'Description 3', 'Descriprion 4'],
#     ['Quantity 4']
# ])

### Dictionary of lists 
newData = pd.DataFrame({
    "Brand": ['Brand A'],
    "Product Title": ['Product Title'],
    "Description 1": ['Description 1'],
    "Description 2": ['Description 2'],
    "Description 3": ['Description 3'],
    "Description 4": ['Description 4'],
    "Quantity": ['Quantity 4']
})

combined_data = pd.concat([existing_data, newData], ignore_index=False)


with pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as write:
    combined_data.to_excel(write, startcol=0, startrow=0, index=False)  # index set to False
```

What you attempting or wanting to do with the Description fields is unclear.
The first paragraph in the question is confusing. It seems you may be indicating scenarios that have more/less Description fields and perhaps may want to add more columns if there are more than the 4 that exist in the template. However cannot be sure.
Also origin of the list of lists that creates 'newData' is not specified so the reasons for it's structure is not known and therefore how it otherwise might be better integrated cannot be commented on.
Also be careful of spelling. There are a few occasions of misspelling 'description' in the Sheet and code and this will cause mismatch of data to columns.

**Additional Information**
Inserting a new column in a DataFrame at your desired location is easy enough.

For example, with your sheet as it is; "Description 5" would need to be inserted after location 8 (Column 8 is where "Description 4" resides).
You would probably want to add to the 'existing_data' before combining the dataframes.
What is contained in the double quotes is the value added to all existing columns.

```
existing_data.insert(8, "Description 5", "")
```

If you do something like the above example and use a Dictionary of Lists then the additional column "Description 5" value will then slot in before integrating into the 'combined_data' Dataframe.
However you would need to determine there is a new column value in the scraped data. Extract the Header name (e.g. 'Description 5') from the data and determine what its location should be.
Again there is insufficient detail to be more specific on implementation.

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution, here is my question is it possible for `Description 5` to come in a new iteration then how can we add a new column `Description 5` just right side from the `Description 4`? actually I am fetching the details from URL through web scrapping and use `for` loop and first `append` the data into list than list data append into the `xlsx` file.

Comment: Certainly you can insert a new column at any column location in a dataframe. I have added some additional details in the answer.